# Spring-AMQP and Direct Reply-To

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I found this RabbitMQ "extension" listed here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html, I set the `RabbitTemplate`'s "replyQueue" with `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` I tried it with an already function RPC call, and it had functioned, but now it just times out.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a fixed reply queue (whether user-specified or the `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`) you have to configure a `<reply-listener/>` - see [the Spring AMQP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e1030). for the `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` you should set the reply container's acknowledge to `NONE` (which is no-ack in RabbitMQ speak).

**CORRECTION:** The `RabbitTemplate` does not currently support Direct reply-to for `sendAndReceive()` operations; you can, however, specify a fixed reply queue (with a reply-listener). Or you can use `rabbitTemplate.execute()` with a `ChannelCallback` to consume the reply from that "queue" (and publish).

I have created a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-448) if you wish to track it.

1.4.1 and above now supports direct reply-to.

Comment: according to [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#d4e1054): "When the template does not use a fixed replyQueue (or is using Direct reply-to - see Section 3.7.1, “RabbitMQ Direct reply-to”) a listener container is not needed." Also, JIRA issue is already closed, however I have the same problem as a topic starter - reply is not received on the client-side.

Comment: Please start a new question, show configuration, and provide version information.

Comment: A common mistake is to mis-type the direct reply-to name (e.g. `amq.rabbitmq.reply.to` instead of `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`).

Comment: I've fixed my issue by updating my rabbitmq server directly from official site.